# How can I use the chat bot in Scrolls?

Tags: scrolls

There is a chat bot in Scrolls called `scrollbot` that is used to monitor user ranking and can be queried to provide both personal and other player information.

I have found mention of the bot in reference material and you can also see the bot user ID in the `General-1` chat room of the game.  However, I can not figure out how to query it.

Has anyone found a `scrollbot` cheat sheet or know how to query it for personal details?  Bonus points if you know anything about the `modbot` that also appears to be in `General-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [Scrollsguide](http://www.scrollsguide.com/wiki/index.php/Scrollsguide_%28Bot%29)?

> **Rank**
>
> The Rank of all players who have competed in Ranked Matches is recorded automatically by the Scrollsguide bot. If you want to view your Rank in-game you can type !rank in the General-1 chatroom. You can also view the rank of another player by typing !rank [Player Name] instead.

There is also [ScrollsBot](http://www.scrollsguide.com/wiki/index.php/ScrollsBot) which is a trading bot

Comment: Yes, that is it.  My question is how do you engage this thing?  Even the reference you posted simply states to "chat with him" when you want to initiate an action.

Comment: From what it says, it seems pretty explicit that you just need to say "!rank" in the general-1 chat room and he'll respond. I do not have scrolls to hand, so I cannot test, however.

Comment: Oh, and `!rank` didn't work for me (or other players) this morning, nor did `help`.  I guess the bot could have been having some issues this morning and maybe I should try again later.